# YouTube link opens in popup window but should open in new tab

Tags: html, video

I have an youtube video on my website with an normal html element. When I click on it in the frontend it opens a new tab for youtube. That works fine.

On another website I did the same with the same code. The problem is that on this website the video plays in a little popup window on the same site and does not open an extra tab.

I also don't want to embed the youtube video. I has to be played in another tab.

Is there a solution to solve the problem?
Unfortunately I am not a professional in typo3.

Thanks in advance!

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
    <div class="box box-blue box-video">
        <a class="col-md-6 video-image fancybox-media" href=https://www.youtube.com/watch  target= "_blank" style="background-image: url('fileadmin/Teaserbox/Vorschaubild.jpg');">
            <img src="btn-play.png" title="Ausbildung" style="margin-top: 150px" />
        </a>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 video-text">
            <h2 class="topline">Titel</h2>
            <p><b>Titel</b></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? Probably there's a js triggered by any class/ID on your element/-s

Comment: Well, you got that „fancybox-media“ class in your link element, which most likely triggers a lightbox/popup to open the video. With preventDefault() in JS, the link won't be executed and target="_blank" is ignored. Try removing that class

Comment: I've edited the question above and added the code. I just changed the links, but that is not the problem in this case. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Alright, so I need to see the site including the javascripts fired …

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your help. Sometimes it's just the little things. Have a good day!